# Debugging Helpers in Win32

Tags: debugging, winapi, platform

What is debugging functions or macros in Visual C++ Win32 Platform like MFC TRACE?

I found debugapi.h but is there a better way for debugging?

Comment: Seems kind of obvious, but  debugger is usually the best tool for this kind of job.

Comment: If for some reason I can't use a debugger, I'll stick MessageBox calls in -- the Win32 equivalent of printf() debugging.

Comment: This is HORRIBLE solution!

Comment: [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362.aspx)

Comment: @drdrjackool Did you managed to use my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Donwload [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) from Sysinternals and use [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362.aspx).

```
// UNICODE
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

    OutputDebugString( L"Hello World\n" );
```

[image: Result]